# CSS.Is is posible to place one element at center of flexbox and one at the right side (large screen) ; but both at center in column in mobile devices?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, responsive-design

Is it possible to make my web app more responsive by placing content in a flexbox such that two cells are side-by-side when viewed on larger displays, but then have both of these elements centered in a single column in the viewport when viewed on smaller screens (i.e., mobile devices)?

For example,

1. On larger screens/viewports it should look like this:

[image: on large screen it should look like this]

2. On smaller screens/viewports (i.e., mobile) it should look like this:

[image: on small mobile screen it should look like this]

Thank you all. I can't figure it out.

Comment: "I can't figure it out" ain't much to work with. What have you tried?

Comment: use `display: grid`. add `@media` rules to change the grid template accordingly

Comment: You can use `flex-wrap` so that the two elements break into sperate rows as soon as they don't fit anymore next to each other. No need for `grid` or `@media` queries. But I'm still waiting for some effort from OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a media-query

```
@media (max-width: 600px)
```

and set

```
flex-direction: column
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this will work for me.